# Python Cartesian Product in a constrained dictonary

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy, hash-map

I want to calculate the Cartesian product of `n` copies of a small list, `marker=[0,1,2]`. I want to use these Cartesian product tuples as keys in a dictionary. The value per each key is to be a numpy array with `n` random floats between 0 and 1.

The only twist is that for each `key:value` pair in the dictionary, if the key has a non-zero number in its index `a`, I want the corresponding value `np.array` to have `np.nan` for the same index.

Below is the function I wrote for that. My question is whether there is a quicker / more efficient way to get the same result.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
def create_constrained_dict(n, markers):
    '''
    Create cartesian product of a the same list repeated n times
    It returns a dictionary whose keys are the cartesian products of the
    input lists. The values of the dictionary are numpy arrays of length 'n'.
    If the corresponding dictionary key element for a value is not zero, we replace the value
    with np.nan.
    Belwo is an example:
    So for some key-value pair, NaN's would be lcoated as follows: 
         d={(0,0,1): np.array([0.1234, 0.7543, np.nan]),
            (1,2,1): np.array([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]),
            (1,0,1): np.array([np.nan, 0.2634, np.nan]),
    } 

    '''
    d = dict()
    for element in itertools.product(*[markers  for i in xrange(n)]):
        d[element] = np.random.uniform(0, 1,n)
        for i in xrange(n):
            if element[i] !=0:
                d[element][i]= np.nan
    return d

rep_num = 3
marker = [0,1,2]
d = create_constrained_dict(rep_num, marker)
```

The output looks like this:

```
print d
{
  (0, 1, 1): array([ 0.84049621,         nan,         nan]),
  (0, 1, 2): array([ 0.17520962,         nan,         nan]),
  (1, 0, 1): array([        nan,  0.96110224,         nan]),
  (0, 2, 1): array([ 0.10395044,         nan,         nan]),
  (2, 2, 0): array([        nan,         nan,  0.60131589]),
  (0, 2, 0): array([ 0.64515576,         nan,  0.05946614]),
  (0, 2, 2): array([ 0.02054272,         nan,         nan]),
  (1, 0, 0): array([        nan,  0.98472074,  0.93688277]),
  (2, 0, 1): array([        nan,  0.64348266,         nan]),
  (1, 2, 0): array([        nan,         nan,  0.71462777]),
  (2, 0, 0): array([        nan,  0.98370414,  0.3517195 ]),
  (1, 2, 1): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (0, 0, 2): array([ 0.29771489,  0.83521032,         nan]),
  (2, 2, 2): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (1, 2, 2): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (2, 0, 2): array([        nan,  0.95682699,         nan]),
  (0, 0, 1): array([ 0.26649784,  0.38120757,         nan]),
  (0, 0, 0): array([ 0.98960411,  0.70080955,  0.25540202]),
  (2, 1, 2): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (1, 1, 1): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (0, 1, 0): array([ 0.94015447,         nan,  0.56849242]),
  (1, 1, 0): array([        nan,         nan,  0.30593067]),
  (2, 1, 0): array([        nan,         nan,  0.74205853]),
  (2, 2, 1): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (2, 1, 1): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (1, 1, 2): array([ nan,  nan,  nan]),
  (1, 0, 2): array([        nan,  0.27788722,         nan])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Instead of `itertools.product(*[markers  for i in xrange(n)])` use `itertools.product(markers, repeat=n)`
- Instead of creating three random values and replace it with `nan` use List Comprehensions.
- `dict([(key, value) for key, value in ...])` creates `dict` object.
- `[bool and [a] or [b]][0]` - safer version of `bool and a or b` - one-linear version of:

  ```
  if bool:
      a
  else:
      b
  ```

And final version:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def create_constrained_dict(n, markers):
    d = dict([(element, np.array([(i == 0 and [np.random.uniform(0, 1)] or [np.nan])[0]
                                  for i in element]))
              for element in itertools.product(markers, repeat=n)])
    return d
```

**EDIT**

Version without `np.array` - 2 times faster (thanks @JoeWallis):

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

def create_constrained_dict(n, markers):
    d = dict([(element, [(i == 0 and [np.random.uniform(0, 1)] or [np.nan])[0]
                         for i in element]))
              for element in itertools.product(markers, repeat=n)])
    return d
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks neater. Is it faster as well? I will test.

Comment: `i == 0 and [np.random.uniform(0, 1)] or [np.nan]` [Ternary](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) operator [was](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html) added at 2.5 . `d = dict([(...)...])` Dict comprehensions are [present](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) in 2.7 as well. Also, line break or two would not hurt.

Comment: I tried with `timeit`, your solution is marginally faster as well - thanks..

Comment: @Zhubarb I tried editing your question to be faster, but it's hard, `np.array` has a large overhead, and numpy doesn't implement `itertools.product` very efficiently either, so using a numpy solution was regularly 2 times slower.

Comment: @JoeWallis, So have you tried a version where dict values are lists (instead of numpy arrays) and it was 2 times faster? If so, it would be very good to have it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your display looked a lot like a n-d array; so I set about trying to create the same pattern, with `numpy` operations.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

Start with a 4d array of `nan`:

```
In [112]: z=np.ones((3,3,3,3))*np.nan
```

Fill selected subarrays with random numbers

```
In [113]: z[0,:,:,0]=np.random.rand(3,3)
In [114]: z[:,0,:,1]=np.random.rand(3,3)
In [115]: z[:,:,0,2]=np.random.rand(3,3)
```

Verify that the resulting array is patterned like the desired dictionary:

```
In [116]: for i,j,k in np.ndindex(3,3,3): 
     ...:     print((i,j,k),z[i,j,k])
     ...:     
(0, 0, 0) [ 0.03527323  0.72731859  0.02793814]
(0, 0, 1) [ 0.9925641   0.47560692         nan]
(0, 0, 2) [ 0.9312088   0.35077862         nan]
(0, 1, 0) [ 0.72458335         nan  0.04496767]
(0, 1, 1) [ 0.42424677         nan         nan]
(0, 1, 2) [ 0.11619154         nan         nan]
(0, 2, 0) [ 0.64655329         nan  0.24431279]
....
(2, 2, 0) [        nan         nan  0.81627296]
(2, 2, 1) [ nan  nan  nan]
(2, 2, 2) [ nan  nan  nan]
```

In 4d display:

```
In [117]: z
Out[117]: 
array([[[[ 0.03527323,  0.72731859,  0.02793814],
         [ 0.9925641 ,  0.47560692,         nan],
         [ 0.9312088 ,  0.35077862,         nan]],

        [[ 0.72458335,         nan,  0.04496767],
         [ 0.42424677,         nan,         nan],
         [ 0.11619154,         nan,         nan]],

        ....
        [[        nan,         nan,  0.81627296],
         [        nan,         nan,         nan],
         [        nan,         nan,         nan]]]])
```

The random fill could be written as a in iteration (details missing)

```
 for i in range(3):
     z[???,i] = np.random.rand(3,3)
```

It's probably not worth trying to avoid the loop.

`intertools.product` is faster than `ndindex`;

The iteration could also be use to map `z` on to a dictionary.

```
{(i,j,k):z[i,j,k,:] for i,j,k in np.ndindex(3,3,3)}
```

But I'm mostly interested in what kind of `n-d` array structure this problem is creating.

==================

The iterative `z` setting code:

```
In [127]: zr=np.random.rand(3,3,3)
In [128]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     idx=[slice(None) for _ in range(4)]
     ...:     idx[-1]=i
     ...:     idx[i]=0
     ...:     z[idx]=zr[i,...]
```

==================

while I'm at it, here's a direct-to-dictionary version:

```
from itertools import product
def foo(*args):
     return np.where(np.array(args)>0, np.nan, np.random.rand(3)) 
{ijk:foo(*ijk) for ijk in product(range(3),repeat=3)}
```